# WebView inside of NestedScrollView can't show all image

Tags: android, html, webview

I've placed a webview inside of a NestedScrollView.

And i'm trying to load html from a html string, but something happens

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://xxx.qpic.cn/xxbiz", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null)
```

And the images in the html  just show the first one and the last one, it is strange

Comment: May be this is an issue with your html code, Once run your html code in any browser manually, if it's giving correct result then webview also will give correct result. Thank you

Comment: Try setting the height of the webview to something fixed other than ```match_parent``` or ```wrap_content```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. But when I remove nestedscrollview, the webview can show all of images.